# Is this method for computing limits valid?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I was shown this 'proof' for proving the limit

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\dfrac{\ln x}{x-1} = 1$

"The expression on the left is the statement of differentiation by first principles for the gradient of the tangent to $y=\ln x$ at $x=1$. Since the gradient of the tangent is 1, via basic differentiation, then the limit must be 1"

I feel that this proof is invalid due to circular arguments (ie: That limit, or equivalent, is used to prove that the derivative of $y= \ln x $ is $\dfrac{1}{x}$ so we cannot use it to prove itself.

Can somebody verify?

EDIT: On a slightly related note, how would one compute this limit without the use of say L'Hopital's or Taylor Series? My instincts are telling me to construct a squeeze using some areas and rectangles.

Comment: Use L'Hopital or Taylor expansion. I don't think it corresponds to circular arguments.

Comment: How do you define the logarithm ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996561/deriving-the-analytical-properties-of-the-logarithm-from-an-algebraic-definition

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you have defined the logarithm. For example, if your definition is
$$\log x = \int_1^x \frac1t\,dt $$
then *by definition* its derivative is $1$ at $1$, with no circularity.

Similarly, if your logarithm is defined as the inverse of the exponential function, then your definition of exp may allow you to prove that $\left.\frac{d}{dx}e^x\right|_{x=0}$ is 1, at which point you can use the rule for the derivative of an inverse function.

Comment: Why is it true "by definition" that the derivative of $x \mapsto \int_1^x 1/t \ dt$ at $1$ is $1$.

Comment: @quid, well strictly speaking by that definition _plus_ the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Okay. Then we agree. :-)

Comment: Can you provide an example(s) of a definition of the logarithm that will result in circularity?

Answer (score 2):

This limit is indeed equivalent to a classical definition of the derivative.

So if the formula for the derivative of $\ln$ is later justified using the limit approach, the argument will be circular.

But if the derivative of $\ln$ is established by other means (such as by inversion of the exponential), then the reasoning can be valid.

There is a third option: if the goal is to actually determine the value of the limit in a practical problem, then all approaches are allowed, including this one, L'hospital and Taylor.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you mean by the derivative of $\ln$ being justified via a limit approach?

Comment: $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really what you are allowed to assume/know already. 
If you know that $(\ln x)' = 1/x$ the argument is valid. If you do not it is at least incomplete (and possibly circular).

I say *possibly* circular, since there are other ways to determine $(\ln x)'\mid_1$ than evaluating that limit.

But, also the evaluation of this limit *is just* determining the derivative of $\ln x$ at $1$, whence the feeling of cicularity. However, to notice this equivalence could well be the point of the exercise.